# Is there any way to declare an abstract property on a class such that any subclasses must not only have that property, but have it as a static member?

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Weapon`:

```
export default abstract class Weapon<T extends WeaponType> {
  public attributes: WeaponAttributeCollection;
  public readonly buildsUpInto: Set<Weapon<T>>;
  public readonly defaultWeapon: boolean;
  public readonly name: WeaponNameByType[T];
}
```

Since `buildsUpInto`, `defaultWeapon`, and `name` will never change at runtime, and because my first use case for a `Weapon` is to be part of a graph I would like each weapon to be its own subclass with those properties as `static` instead of just being `readonly` (this way when comparing for equality between two vertices I can rely on the class itself and not a reference to an instance of the class).

However this doesn't seem to be enforceable with TypeScript.

```
export default abstract class Weapon<T extends WeaponType> {
  public attributes: WeaponAttributeCollection;
  static abstract buildsUpInto: Set<Weapon<T>>; // ERROR
  static abstract defaultWeapon: boolean; // ERROR
  static abstract name: WeaponNameByType[T]; // ERROR
}
```

TypeScript doesn't support this (and it seems in general this isn't a thing in other OOP languages). So then is there any way to accomplish this idea without saying every single subclass of `Weapon` `extends SomeInterface`?

Maybe there is a better pattern entirely to accomplish what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Static properties of a class are plain object properties of the constructor function itself. This means that when you access the property from the outside, you're going to do something like this:

```
const weapon: Weapon = getAWeaponSomehow();
doSomethingWith(weapon.constructor.buildsUpInto);
```

This naturally lends itself to an interface:

```
export type WeaponConstructor<W extends WeaponClass, T extends WeaponType> =
  new () => W 
  & {
    buildsUpInto: Set<WeaponConstructor<unknown>>,
    defaultWeapon: boolean,
    name: WeaponNameByType[T]
  }

export abstract class WeaponClass<T extends WeaponType> {
  public attributes: WeaponAttributeCollection;
}

export type Weapon<W extends WeaponClass, T extends WeaponType> = 
  W<T> & { constructor: WeaponConstructor<W, T> }
```

---

As for whether I would actually do this, I think it's mostly a good idea, in that the ability to show weapon types on a graph would be good to do without instantiating actual weapons. However, you could probably do an easier job of encoding this if you use static factory objects (with the static properties on them) instead of putting them on the constructor - then every Weapon has a reference to the WeaponFactory that created it and you can call it a day.

Plus, I can think of a handful of potential future features in which these static properties *would* change, such as being able to rename an instantiated weapon or having an instance of weapon that secretly has a different build order.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm having a little trouble conceptualizing how to apply a static factory method to my use case. Would the static method exist on the `Weapon` class itself, or would it be part of a factory class?

Comment: @ChristopherFimbel It would be a separate factory class (or factory object). The `Weapon` object (which, presumably, is what's actually in your character's inventory) would not exist on your graph - the `WeaponFactory` would.